# Laravel 5.1 after Registration Auth::attempt no access to the user data on another page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am having an issue with accessing the authenticated user data once registered on the system.

After carrying out some validation within my Registration process I have this line:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array(
        'username' => $customer->username,
        'password' => $data['password']
    ))) {
        return redirect('profile-setup');
    }
```

I have tried die to see the user data within this if statement, like this:

```
dd(Auth::user());
```

This actually works and I can see the user data.

However When I go to the blade profile-setup, I tried the same die but I am getting a null value.

I am not sure as to what I have missed out.

If there's anything that needs to be provided from my end please just let me know. Any help with be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if any of this is present in your case :

- Specifying `protected $primaryKey = 'user__table_id_column_name';` in user model
- If you see the method signature inside the larvel's core you will see :

public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true){
..
}

So try passing second argument to attempt as `true` and see if it persists. This should not be the case as this should happen automatically but try once for safe fide

- Remove echo statements if you have any for debugging
- Check if you are calling Auth::logout() anywhere by mistake before the last dd
- try redirect()->intended('profile-setup');

For more help follow just check thread : [Laravel Auth:attempt() will not persist login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603347/laravel-authattempt-will-not-persist-login)