# auth laravel always return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I often create a login with Laravel, and it runs smoothly, but I don't understand the actual process run by Laravel `php artisan make:auth`. and now I want to try creating this login process myself to understand the actual process

I'm trying to make the login process run by myself without Laravel `make:auth`. create a user table with a password that hashed. when logging in `Auth::attempt` is always `false`, why?

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

This function is in the documentation of Laravel Manually Authenticating Users
if i `dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));` always return `false`, so it can't go to route `/home`:

and my register controller like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
    ]);

    return redirect::back();
}
```

how to deal with this?

Comment: are you hashing your passwords when registering a new user?

Comment: yes of course. my password for testing is 123456, and after hash is $2y$10$XU46gwygzpIv1yC.IK035ewRzyWLU67A0qatRrYzq09z98ePdJsgS

Comment: please try to hash it before `if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {` using the same hashing method when registering a new user and post what you get

Comment: $email      = Input::get('email');
$password   = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$credentials = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password];
i change like this but still false, why?

Comment: please update your question with your register method

Comment: Make sure you are using right guard to authenticate

Comment: how to set guard?

Comment: Its inside config/auth.php you may setup guard there but if you're using users table then its already all set.

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603347/laravel-authattempt-will-not-persist-login) helps?

Answer (score 0):

i think laravel use json callback and middlware and some handled session and cookie
better use basic auth
and check by step to all  work currectly in front to end
and see data send to backend currectly

Comment: yes i know. now the attempt can be true, now the problem is that auth returns null, why?